# iPhone app submission without a website

Tags: iphone, web, app-store

I'm just about ready to submit my iPhone app to iTunes Connect, but they require a company website. I don't have a website, and I can't afford a domain registration and hosting. Is there a way to submit an application without a website URL?

Comment: They won't allow you to bypass the required field, I would just create a blogspot account and give them that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily create a website using [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/). I would suggest that you create one so that there is a place for users to find out about your application, find documentation, etc.